# Blender crashes when assigning materials from script - is it a bug?

Tags: scripting

I wrote a script. In one part of the script, there is this line:

`base_object.data.materials.append (changeable_material)`

Whenever I try to run the script, Blender just shuts down, immediately, without any error or anything, within a fraction of a second.

`base_object` is a cube generated by the script, `changeable_material` is a precreated material. I don't have much experience with Blender scripting.

Is this a mistake in my code or a bug? If not a bug, how do I fix it?

Edit:

Relevant parts of the script:

```
import bpy

matrix_size = 3

matrix = []
cubes = []
materials = []
matrix_range = range (matrix_size)

changeable_material = bpy.data.materials.get("Material")

material_value = 0

for i in range (matrix_size):
    matrix.append([])
    cubes.append ([])
    materials.append (changeable_material.copy ())
    materials [-1].node_tree.nodes.get("Value").outputs [0].default_value = material_value
    material_value += 1 / matrix_size
    for j in range (matrix_size):
        matrix [-1].append ((i * j) % matrix_size)
        cubes [-1].append (0)

(...)

#removes all unused materials
for material in bpy.data.materials:
    if (not (material.users)):
        bpy.data.materials.remove(material)

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
base_object = bpy.context.object
base_object.name = "base cube"
base_object.data.materials.append (changeable_material)

bpy.context.scene.objects.active = base_object

(...)

for i in range (matrix_size):
    for j in range (matrix_size):
        if cubes [i][j].data.materials:
            cubes [i][j].data.materials[0] = materials [matrix [i][j]]
```

Here is the whole:

```
import bpy

matrix_size = 3

(...)

materials = []
matrix_range = range (matrix_size)

changeable_material = bpy.data.materials.get("Material")

material_value = 0

for i in range (matrix_size):
    (...)
    materials.append (changeable_material.copy ())
    materials [-1].node_tree.nodes.get("Value").outputs [0].default_value = material_value
    material_value += 1 / matrix_size
    for j in range (matrix_size):
        matrix [-1].append ((i * j) % matrix_size)
        cubes [-1].append (0)

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action = "SELECT")

for i in bpy.data.objects:
    if ((i.type == "CAMERA") or (i.type == "LAMP") or (i.name == "Material_Holder")):
        i.select = False
bpy.ops.object.delete()

#removes all unused materials
for material in bpy.data.materials:
    if (not (material.users)):
        bpy.data.materials.remove(material)

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
base_object = bpy.context.object
base_object.name = "base cube"
base_object.data.materials.append (changeable_material)

base_object.scale = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)

bpy.context.scene.objects.active = base_object

arrayOne = base_object.modifiers.new (name = "arrayOne", type = "ARRAY")
arrayOne.count = matrix_size
arrayTwo = base_object.modifiers.new (name = "arrayTwo", type = "ARRAY")
arrayTwo.count = matrix_size
arrayTwo.relative_offset_displace [0] = 0
arrayTwo.relative_offset_displace [1] = 1

bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply (modifier = "arrayOne")
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply (modifier = "arrayTwo")

base_object.select = True
bpy.ops.mesh.separate (type = "LOOSE")

for i in bpy.data.objects:
    if ("cube" in i.name):
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action = "DESELECT")
        i.select = True
        bpy.ops.object.origin_set (type = "ORIGIN_CENTER_OF_MASS")
        cubes [int (i.location [0])][int (i.location [1])] = i

for i in range (matrix_size):
    for j in range (matrix_size):
        if cubes [i][j].data.materials:
            cubes [i][j].data.materials[0] = materials [matrix [i][j]]
```

Comment: You should probably post your relevant code, for others to check...

Comment: The line is correct assuming the variables contain correct information. The issue must be in another part of the code. Without seeing the code it is impossible to say what is wrong.

Comment: Try reducing the code to the minimal amount needed to reproduce the crash. Usually that gives you more insight, and also saves us from having to understand all of your stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code snippets given, it's difficult to reproduce the error.

Here's my guess:

If the object with the name `'Material_Holder'` does not have the material referenced by the variable `changeable_material`, that material will get removed (in block with the comment `#removes all unused materials`). There would be problem if later this (removed) material is appended to any object (`base_object.data.materials.append (changeable_material)`). The crash could be related to this.

So if the `changeable_material` is needed later in the code, the condition should be `if (not (material.users)) and material is not changeable_material` before calling `remove`.

Comment: The problem indeed was the material I was trying to assign did not exist at the time at that time. Moving the "remove all unused materials" to the top fixed this